# Dropdown menu hidden behind slideshow container?

Tags: drop-down-menu, z-index, slideshow

We have a main index page with a dropdown menu and slide show, and the z-index works fine, but in our other pages, we removed the slideshow and left the dropdown menu. But for some reason in the pages without the slideshow, the dropdown menu gets hidden behind the container the slideshow used to be, despite the removal of all slideshow HTML. This leads me to believe it is a CSS issue.

Any suggestions would be well appreciated!

**Here's the HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Stigler Public Schools</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="\\stigler-web\web\New Website\caleab\stiglerstylesheet.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <img class="logo" src="sps_logo.png" alt="Stigler Public Schools">
    <p class="header">Stigler Public Schools</p>
    <div class="nav">
      <ul class="navigation">
      <a class="main" href="#url">District</a>
  <li class="n1"><a href="\\stigler-web\web\New Website\caleab\District\hs\hs.html">High School</a></li>
  <li class="n2"><a href="\\stigler-web\web\New Website\caleab\District\ms\ms.html">Middle School</a></li>
  <li class="n3"><a href="\\stigler-web\web\New Website\caleab\District\gs\gs.html">Grade School</a></li>
  <li class="n4"><a href="\\stigler-web\web\New Website\caleab\District\admin\admin.html">Administration</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navigation">
      <a class="main" href="#url">Resources</a>
      <li class="n1"><a href="school_calendar.html" target="main">School Calender</a></li>
      <li class="n2"><a href="cafeteria_menus.html" target="main">Menus</a></li>
      <li class="n3"><a href="employment_opportunities.html" target="main">Employment</a></li>
      <li class="n4"><a href="counselor.html" target="main">Counseling</a></li>
      <li class="n5"><a href="https://wengage.com/Stigler/Login/AttemptLogin?ReturnUrl=%2fstigler.html">Grade Book</a></li>
      <li class="n6"><a href="http://www.jostens.com/yearbooks/high-school-yearbooks.html">Yearbook</a></li>
    </ul>
    </td>
    <ul class="navigation">
      <a class="main" href="#url">Organizations</a>
      <li class="n1"><a href="" target="main">Athletics</a></li>
      <li class="n2"><a href="#" target="main">Music</a></li>
      <li class="n3"><a href="" target="main">Drama</a></li>
      <li class="n4"><a href="#">FFA</a></li>
      <li class="n5"><a href="#">A-Z</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ul class="navigation">
      <a class="main" href="#url">Board Of Education</a>
        <li class="n1"><a href="board_of_education.html" target="main">Information</a></li>
      <li class="n2"><a href="policy.html#" target="main">Meetings</a></li>
      <li class="n3"><a href="#">Policies</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

**And Here's the CSS**

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  outline: none;
  border: 0px;
}

body {
  background-image: url(background.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0px auto;
  padding: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

h1 {
  border-top: none;
  border-left: none;
  border-bottom: 5px groove red;
  border-right: none;
  color: #e60000;
  font-family: century gothic;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FF000;
}

h2 {
  font-family: century gothic;
}

h3 {
  font-family: century gothic;
}

h5 {
  font-family: californian fb;
  font-szie: 1.15em;
}

p {
  border-top: none;
  border-left: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-right: none;
  font-family: californian fb;
  font-size: 1.15em;
}

table#sitelinks td {
  font-size: 1.15em;
}

table#sitelinks tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #fff
}

table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #fff
}

table tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #eee
}

hr {
  border-top: none;
  border-left: none;
  border-bottom: 5px groove red;
  border-right: none;
  font-family: californian fb;
  font-size: 1.15em;
}

th {
  text-align: left;
  font-family: century gothic;
  padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
  font-size: 1.15em;
}

td {
  font-family: century gothic;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1em;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.blue {
  color: blue;
}

.bottomborder {
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 5px groove red;
}

a:link {
  color: #e60000;
  text-decoration: none
}

a:visited {
  color: #e60000;
  text-decoration: none
}

a:hover {
  color: #e60000;
  text-decoration: none
}

a:active {
  color: #e60000;
  text-decoration: none
}

.logo {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 160px;
  width: 160px;
}

.header {
  padding-left: 140px
}

a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #999;
}

.navwrapper {}

.nav {
  width: 79.31%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0px auto;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}

a:hover {
  color: #FF0000;
}


/* NAVIGATION */

.navigation {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  background: #FF0000;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10
}

.navigation,
.navigation a.main {
  border-radius: 0px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px;
}

.navigation:hover,
.navigation:hover a.main {
  border-radius: 0px 0px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 0 0;
}

.navigation a.main {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 40px;
  font: bold 15px/40px arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.navigation:hover a.main {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04);
}

.navigation li {
  width: 250px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #F7F7F7;
  font: normal 12px/40px arial, sans-serif !important;
  color: #999;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  transform-origin: 50% 0%;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(-90deg);
  -o-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(-90deg);
  transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(-90deg);
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 30;
  overflow: visible;
}

.navigation li:nth-child(even) {
  background: #F5F5F5;
}

.navigation li:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #EFEFEF;
}

.navigation li.n1 {
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s linear 0.4s;
  -o-transition: 0.2s linear 0.4s;
  transition: 0.2s linear 0.4s;
}

.navigation li.n2 {
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s linear 0.3s;
  -o-transition: 0.2s linear 0.3s;
  transition: 0.2s linear 0.3s;
}

.navigation li.n3 {
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s linear 0.2s;
  -o-transition: 0.2s linear 0.2s;
  transition: 0.2s linear 0.2s;
}

.navigation li.n4 {
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s linear 0.1s;
  -o-transition: 0.2s linear 0.1s;
  transition: 0.2s linear 0.1s;
}

.navigation li.n5 {
  border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s linear 0s;
  -o-transition: 0.2s linear 0s;
  transition: 0.2s linear 0s;
}

.navigation:hover li {
  -webkit-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(0deg);
  -o-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(0deg);
  transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(0deg);
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s linear 0s;
  -o-transition: 0.2s linear 0s;
  transition: 0.2s linear 0s;
}

.navigation:hover .n2 {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.1s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.1s;
  transition-delay: 0.1s;
}

.navigation:hover .n3 {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.2s;
  transition-delay: 0.2s;
}

.navigation:hover .n4 {
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.3s;
  transition-delay: 0.3s;
}

.navigation:hover .n5 {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.4s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.4s;
  transition-delay: 0.4s;
}

.navigation:hover .n6 {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0.5s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0.5s;
  transition-delay: 0.5s
}


/* End Navigation */


/*Slideshow */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slideshowimg {
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: none;
  border: 2px solid #ffffff
}


/* Slideshow container */

.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  min-width: 1000px;
  min-height: 500px;
  max-height: 500px;
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0px auto;
  clear: both;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* Caption text */

.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Number text (1/3 etc) */

.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}


/* The dots/bullets/indicators */

.dot {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active {
  background-color: #717171;
}


/* Fading animation */

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: .4
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1
  }
}


/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */

@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .text {
    font-size: 11px
  }
}


/* End Slideshow */
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this on my own. I realized that since there was no more content under the drop-down menu, the page technically ended, hence the disappearing menu. At least that's my conclusion. After adding the intended content to the page, they worked just fine.